# Sharing session between .NET framework app and .NET Core Razor pages app

Tags: .net, session, asp.net-core

Accessing session information stored in SQL Server for .NET framework app in .NET core razor pages app.

Session stored in SQL Server with .NET framework is stored differently than .NET Core. Is there any solution with which we can map corresponding columns and access it? ASPStateTempSessions table stores session information for .NET Web app.

```
services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
          {
              options.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("SessionDB");
              options.SchemaName = "dbo";
              options.TableName = "ASPStateTempSessions";
          });
```

HttpContext.Session.GetString("firstname") is null in .NET Core app.

Comment: Simply, no. You're dealing with more than just storage here, though. There's also encryption at play. Due to MVC 5's support for OWIN, you can actually make ASP.NET MVC 5 apps and ASP.NET Core apps share data protection providers (based on OWIN), which allows one to decrypt what the other encrypts. However, if you're dealing with something like a Web Forms app, you're out of luck. And, of course, that doesn't solve the SQL backing problem.

Comment: Even though they share "ASP.NET" in their name is best to think of them as entirely different frameworks because they are. You wouldn't expect to be able to share session state between an ASP.NET app and a Ruby on Rails app, so it's not all that surprising to not be able to share with an ASP.NET Core app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to read session information in .NET Core app but able to achieve what I wanted with this npm package https://github.com/dazinator/AspNetCore.LegacyAuthCookieCompat